# How to adjust div size responsively over an image?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am attempting to create a textbox over part of an image in a responsive Bootstrap setup.

My final aim is to be able to update this textbox to what a user types in below in a form using jQuery.

The website needs to be responsive, and I am trying to find out how to get the `div` containing the textbox to adjust responsively so that it always displays over the same part of the image, and to the same size of the image.

**My exact problem is this:**

The image is of a card; at full screen my textbox sits perfectly over the card. When I reduce the size of the screen, the textbox remains the size it was previously and is no longer positioned exactly above the image of the card.

Thanks for any help you may lend!

Comment: please post some code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions need to be more specific and include a sample of your work. It's hard for us to help, otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the documentation on [responsive layouts using the bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Have a look at the [grid template examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) too.

The relevant bit will be understanding how the particular size classes work:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">...</div>
</div>
```

Here, col-xs-12 means under a mobile, the div takes up the entire row width.  The col-md-4 part refers to a larger medium, where it only takes up 1/3 of the row width.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I ended up changing the size of the box manually using @media queries.